# Is there a way to get the BIOS version from inside Linux?

Tags: linux, bios

I want to get the BIOS version from Linux without going directly to the BIOS.

I mean, is there a way to get the BIOS version from inside Linux?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

## Without superuser privileges

It is as simple as reading the following file:

```
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version
1.1.3
```

---

## With superuser privileges

Use [dmidecode](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode):

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.1.3
```

Also, you might have to install this package, which is available in:

- Linux i386, x86-64, ia64
- FreeBSD i386, amd64
- NetBSD i386, amd64
- OpenBSD i386, amd64
- BeOS i386
- Solaris x86
- Haiku i586

Comment: The `/sys/....` approach should be used if possible.

Comment: I believe `dmidecode` only works if `/dev/mem` is available, which isn't the case on modern distros.

Comment: @forest what's modern do you mean? At least it works in my Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: Do you have a readable `/dev/mem` on that system?

Comment: @forest yes. I don't see any distros with desktop environment don't have /dev/mem

Comment: Most of it _have_ it, but it isn't readable (compile-time feature in the kernel). I can think of Fedora and Debian which are that way.

Comment: @forest My debian testing/buster machine with normal debian Linux kernel has a working dmidecode. So I’m not sure what you’re saying here.

Comment: @forest compile time feature is for writing restricting, not reading.

Comment: Maybe `dmidecode` only requires the first megabyte which IIRC is whitelisted.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `lshw` , `hwinfo` , `inxi` and `hardinfo` (DMI):

```
# lshw -class memory
# hwinfo --bios
$ inxi -M
$ hardinfo
```

The above command should work after installing them through your package manager.

Only the first answer proposed by [@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm) allow you the get bios information without installing an additional package:

> `$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios*`

Comment: hwinfo and hardinfo are not installed by default on Linux Mint.

Comment: And none of them are available by default on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 5):

I was wandering in `/sys` folder then I went into `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables` then got two files `DMI` and `smbios_entry_point`. If you read `DMI` file then in my case first word was `LENOVO` and second word was `BIOS version`. I know this is not simple and straight answer but you can get more information regarding your `pc` from this file.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep "BIOS Information" -A10 | grep -e "Version:" -e "Vendor:"
```

Comment: This sort of text filtering is fragile. Much better to make a specific request for the specific information you want, as shown by cuonglm.

Comment: will BIOS version is meaning full without vendor name?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry.